# ERROR 1064 (42000) on INSERT query

Tags: mysql, sql

My SQL query (as part of a trigger) is:

`INSERT INTO product_pricing_data (pp_id, group_id, var, data)
VALUES (@newppid, NEW.group_id, NEW.var, newprice);`

The error message I'm getting is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 54

Not very useful!  If anyone has any suggestions, greatly received.

Comment: What is `new`?  You haven't defined it in the statement.

Comment: Updated description, this insert is within a trigger.

Comment: newprice and @newppid are also set within the trigger

Comment: @glambert . . . This particular statement looks ok.  What are the lines around it?

Answer (score 0):

There was a missing END IF; a few lines down from the line the error message pointed to - adding the END IF; removed the syntax error and the trigger created successfully.